# My Software Center won't open - Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apt, software-center

When I try to reinstall or remove Software Center, it says

```
E: Malformed line 7 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (type)
E: The List of sources could not be read.
```

Please help.

Comment: Open terminal and paste the output of command `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` please.

Comment: deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
/dev/null


/dev/null

Comment: (xenial)drippydj@localhost:~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
/dev/null 
@mbiber

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you the problem.  There is a problem on the 7th line of the sources list.

The privileges on that file require that you be root to edit it.  in a terminal window, you can

```
cd /etc/apt
sudo nano sources.list
```

The system will ask for your password (unless you've done some magic with sudo) and then dump you into the top of the file in the nano editor. Press the down arrow 6 times.

All comment lines should start with a hash (#).

If the line is not a comment line, it should start with deb or deb-src. Compare it to other lines that are not commented, and you may see the error.  At worst, as a temporary fix, you can add a hash (#) at the beginning of the line to ignore it as a comment.

Ctrl+O (the letter, not the number) to save, Ctrl+X to exit.

Comment: this doesn't work because when i type it it says:      bash: cd/etc/apt: No such file or directory @poorplanning

Comment: You need a space between cd and /etc/apt